# manipulate response from get not working in conditional statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, get

I have the following code, but the problem is when I try to set up conditional statements using the value retrieved from the php, (getstate), it passes through the if statements even it doesn't match. For example, if the response is  1 getstate is 1, but it will execute the code for when the getstate is 2. What is wrong?

```
 var getstate =""; 
    $.get('getstate.php', {
                    email: emailaddress,
                    country: 'DE',
                    lang: lang,
                    source: '1304_Spring_dly'
                }, function (data) {

            getstate = data;

    if ( getstate = "2" ){

        $('#mch-overlay').fadeIn(300);

                } else if ( getstate = "1" ){
                    $('#mch-overlay').fadeIn(300);
                    });

              } else {
                    $('p.error').hide();
                      }

            }); /*end .GET */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conditionals require `==` or `===`, using just `=` sets the value, and usually trimming the value to make sure there is no whitespace is a good idea :

```
$.get('getstate.php', {
           email  : emailaddress,
           country: 'DE',
           lang   : lang,
           source : '1304_Spring_dly'
    }, function (data) {
           var getstate = $.trim( data );
           if ( getstate == "2" ){
               $('#mch-overlay').fadeIn(300);
           } else if ( getstate == "1" ){
               $('#mch-overlay').fadeIn(300);
           } else {
               $('p.error').hide();
           }
});
```

Also notice that you're doing the same thing in the conditional, so it could probably have been shortened to just if / else.

Comment: thanks for that, youre right! Is there a way I can use the variable getstate outside of that function? I have tried and it always comes out as empty.

Comment: That's because ajax is asynchronous, so you can't expect the variable to be set before the ajax call has completed, and that is why the complete callback is there.

Comment: do you know how I can do that? Using the callback as you say?

Comment: The callback is what you're using now, inside `function (data) { ... }`, that is the callback function for when the ajax call has completed, and that is the only place where you can be sure that `data` is really `data`.